# Sticky plugin doesen't work on WordPress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, sticky

I have this code to create a sticky element in wordpress.

```
jQuery('.test').sticky({
  topSpacing: 80, // Space between element and top of the viewport
  zIndex: 100, // z-index
  stopper: "#bar" // Id, class, or number value
  stickyClass: "false" ,// Class applied to element when it's stuck
});
```

The sticky library is http://github.com/andrewhenderson/jsticky/.

When the above code  `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing } after property list` will come . Can you help me ?

Comment: Have you got a jsfiddle handy?

Comment: You’re missing a comma after the `stopper` key/value in your Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the looks of things you're missing a comma on the `stopper` line.

It should be -

```
jQuery('.test').sticky({
  topSpacing: 80, // Space between element and top of the viewport
  zIndex: 100, // z-index
  stopper: "#bar", // Id, class, or number value
  stickyClass: "false" ,// Class applied to element when it's stuck
});
```